# Interjection between subordinate and main clauses

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses, interjections, independent-clauses

I have a question about this modest sentence for which I have no context except that it came to me. Then I wondered about its grammaticality.

> Because it wasn’t my job—I didn’t work there—I left.

Is this aside, “I didn’t work there,” grammatical? If so, is it punctuated correctly? And also, does it actually belong to the subordinate clause?

Thank you!

Comment: Strictly parenthetical information (something you could put inside parentheses) has no grammatical role whatsoever with respect to the surrounding text. If you can remove it entirely and the rest of the sentence is fine, then there's no problem. If you remove it and the rest of the sentence becomes ungrammatical, then the rest of the sentence wasn't grammatical to start with. Nor is there any reason to assume that what's *inside* the parentheses must be grammatical—although it often in. It's merely an aside.

Comment: No subordinate clause here, Three sentences strung together with dashes.